How to add Indentity Account to a existing app with Microsoft Identity
I have created a Blazor Webassembly (.NET 7) which I setup the Microsoft identity upon creation, this is for our employees to access the application, now we have users that are not directly hired by our company, and they don't have a Microsoft account (on our Azure Ad), so what I'm trying to achieve now is to combine both Microsoft Identity and Identity Account, but currently I don't know how to do it.
Can someone teach me how to do combine those two authentications?
I haven't tried anything yet.

Can I suggest you spin up practice app with Identity and learn how to configure external providers and bring your Microsoft accounts in this way. There are articles on both MSLearn and Duende's website on how to do this.

You need set a different auth schema for the identity or else. Have you consider create a custom role inside the AAD which is no need to modify current project?
